# How to Change label text color by letter by letter with time interval?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uiviewanimation

I tried below code:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(myTimerMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void)myTimerMethod:(NSTimer*)timer
{

    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.22 alpha:1.0];

}
```

but i want like below image type to change color.

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is happening with the code you posted, and what exactly do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UILabel now supports attributed string. So you can do something similar to following

```
int lengthOfTextToColor = 0;
NSMutableAttributedString *textString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"I think you are making a karaoke app"];

-(void)colorChangeTimer:(NSTimer *)timer {
    lengthOfTextToColor ++;
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, lengthOfTextToColor);
    NSDictionary *colorAttribute = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blueColor]};
    [textString setAttributes: colorAttribute range:range];
    self.label.attributedText = textString;
}
```

But attributed string has its limitations. 
If you are looking to implement really fancy text, pull up your socks and check [Text Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) and CoreText Framework. You can find many [tutorials for Core Text](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/core-text-tutorial-for-ios-making-a-magazine-app)

Comment: Thank You its working for me...but add to this also                  if (lengthOfTextToColor==[textString length]) {
        [timer invalidate];
        return;
    }

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `NSMutableAttributedString`:

```
_string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"your string"];
_index = 0;
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(yourSelector) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

- (void)yourSelector {
    [_string setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]} range:NSMakeRange(_index, 1)];
    [label setAttributedText:_string];
    _index++;
}
```